# android issue loading big Image in a ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, jpeg

I have a question is usall that a jpg image of 1MB become a 12 MB Bitmap? I'm just doing a screen spalsh  that load a big image of 1MB  in a ImageView (fullscreen) and I got this error:

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 27.724MB for 12582928-byte allocation
08-14 21:31:13.302: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-14 21:31:13.302: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
08-14 21:31:13.302: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:447)
08-14 21:31:13.312: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
08-14 21:31:13.312: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
08-14 21:31:13.312: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-14 21:31:13.312: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
08-14 21:31:13.312: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
08-14 21:31:13.312: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-14 21:31:13.312: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
08-14 21:31:13.322: I/dalvikvm(15434):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
```

Answer (score 0):

JPEG is the compressed image, but to show on the screen it must be loaded as a bitmap and each pixel is translated to a color value, so with 8 bit per color and one for alpha you have 4 bytes for each pixel.

So the size of the JPEG doesn't matter, it matters the width and height size of the image.

Edit:

To have a smaller bitmap in memory, see this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for scaling down your bitmap to the size occupied on screen.

ImageView and other Views doesn't scale the bitmap to size, the bitmap is the original. But you can scale down the bitmap using the link above and keep the memory use low.

Comment: so how can I do to reduce the weight and keep the image quality I scaled the image to ajust the screen size but still the wigth is huge.